# Can I swap the CapsLock key and the left Ctrl key in the remmina RDP session?

Tags: keyboard-layout, remote-desktop, rdp

I'd like to swap the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys always. So I'm using **GNOME Tweak Tools** now.

I frequently need to connect to a remote Windows 10 server, so I connected the server using the Remmina program, but the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys aren't swapped. Are there any solutions for this?

I tried changing the `/etc/default/keyboard` file and changing the registry 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout\Scancode Map' in the remote Windows 10 server, but they couldn't solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, for you time saving, I would recommend to buy a new keyboard which the control key is next to A key. #1 HHKB Pro 2/Type-S or some variants of it. #2 Sun Type 5 unix or Zenith Z-150.

Answer (score 0):

Install [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) on Windows 10, create a `.ahk` file with the following contents:

```
Capslock::Control
```

Add that file to the startup folder (type `shell:startup` on Windows Run dialog box).

Comment: ようこそ AskUbuntu へ Windowsでの解法は Off-topic となり低評価が与えられます、お気をつけて Welcome to AskUbuntu, you answer should be the way how you resolve this in Ubuntu.